# MFC CString Constructor action

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings

```
CString Str1 = "ABC";
CString Str2 = Str1 + "123"; // Understandable
CString Str3 = "123" + Str1; // How does it work? Is there data overriding?
```

Does the last operation use CString '+' operator overloading, although Str1 is on the right of the '+'?
Thanks of answering.

Comment: What's the reason for accepting the proposed answer, that doesn't answer your question, nor link to the correct documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CString Str3 = "123" + Str1;
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa300546%28v%3Dvs.60%29) you can see the various overloads of `operator+` that `CString` supports and one of them includes the above example.

**Note:** Concatenating two string literals like below is not supported for that would be equivalent to adding two pointers.

```
CString Str3 = "123" + "456"
```

Comment: `CString` isn't Microsoft's version of `std::string`. It is part of Microsoft's MFC. MFC's `CString` is **completely** unrelated to `std::string`.

Comment: I said, "seems to be". I did not know for sure. But I can update the answer to remove reference to std::string part because that is not really necessary I think.

Comment: That still links to outdated documentation, that's no longer correct.

Answer (score 3):

The MFC/ATL [CStringT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class) class template provides the following [operator+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#operator_add) operators as free functions:

> ```
> friend CStringT operator+(const CStringT& str1, const CStringT& str2);
> friend CStringT operator+(const CStringT& str1, PCXSTR psz2);
> friend CStringT operator+(PCXSTR psz1, const CStringT& str2,);
> friend CStringT operator+(char ch1, const CStringT& str2,);
> friend CStringT operator+(const CStringT& str1, char ch2);
> friend CStringT operator+(const CStringT& str1, wchar_t ch2);
> friend CStringT operator+(wchar_t ch1, const CStringT& str2);
> ```

The statement `CString Str3 = "123" + Str1;` cannot use a class member, as there is no class object on the left-hand side of the `+` expression, and no user-defined implicit conversion operator. It needs to invoke a free function, and uses the overload taking a [PCXSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt-predefined-types) argument.

Note, that this implies, that your project is set to use ANSI (MBCS) encoding. This is not generally desirable. Use Unicode instead, either by setting the appropriate preprocessor symbols (see [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings) for details), or by explicitly using the wide character versions (`CStringW`) and prepending string literals with an `L` (`L"123"`).